# Firebase database data type conversion error

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I was doing a project and got this error:

```
Fatal Exception: com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.example.codechat.InstantMessage
       at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertBean(CustomClassMapper.java:436)
       at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToClass(CustomClassMapper.java:232)
       at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertToCustomClass(CustomClassMapper.java:80)
       at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(DataSnapshot.java:203)
       at com.example.codechat.CustomAdapter.getItem(CustomAdapter.java:77)
       at com.example.codechat.CustomAdapter.getView(CustomAdapter.java:96)
       at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:3073)
       at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1305)
       at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1212)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20236)
       at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:716)
       at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:462)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20236)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6333)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
       at androidx.appcompat.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:146)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20236)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6333)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:747)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:629)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20236)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6333)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20236)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6333)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:747)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:629)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20236)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6333)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
       at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:3140)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20236)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2704)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1656)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1948)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1544)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7607)
       at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:911)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:686)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:622)
       at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:897)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7402)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

This my custom adapter:

```
package com.example.codechat;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

import com.google.firebase.database.ChildEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Activity myActivity;
    private DatabaseReference myDB;
    private String username;
    private ArrayList<DataSnapshot> dataSnapshots;
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    DatabaseReference chatsRef = rootRef.child("Chats");
    ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                dataSnapshots.add(dataSnapshot);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            
        }
    };


       

       

       

    public CustomAdapter(Activity activity, DatabaseReference ref, String name){
        myActivity = activity;
        myDB = ref.child("Chats");
        username = name;
        dataSnapshots = new ArrayList<>();
        myDB.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
    }
    static class ViewHolder{
        TextView sender;
        TextView message;
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return dataSnapshots.size();
    }

    @Override
    public InstantMessage getItem(int i) {
        DataSnapshot snapshot = dataSnapshots.get(i);
        return snapshot.getValue(InstantMessage.class);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        if(view == null){
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) myActivity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.chat_list_view, viewGroup, false);
            final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.sender = view.findViewById(R.id.text);
            viewHolder.message = view.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            viewHolder.layoutParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) viewHolder.sender.getLayoutParams();
            view.setTag(viewHolder);
        }
        final InstantMessage message = getItem(i);
        final ViewHolder viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        boolean isMe = message.getUser().equals(username);//Error
        row_style(isMe, viewHolder);
        String messager = message.getMessage();
        String author = message.getUser();
        viewHolder.sender.setText(author);
        viewHolder.message.setText(messager);
        return view;
    }
    private void row_style(boolean ism, ViewHolder hold){
        if(ism){
            hold.layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.START;
            hold.sender.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
            hold.message.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.speech_bubble_orange);
        }else{
            hold.layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.END;
            hold.sender.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
            hold.message.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.speech_bubble_green);
        }
    }
    public void confusing(){
        myDB.removeEventListener(valueEventListener);
    }

}
```

This is my ChatActivity:

```
package com.example.codechat;

import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

public class ChatActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private String username;
    private ListView list;
    private EditText text;
    private ImageButton james_bond;
    private DatabaseReference ethan;
    private CustomAdapter adapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat);
        showDisplay();
        ethan = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        list = findViewById(R.id.listView);
        text = findViewById(R.id.editTextT);
        james_bond = findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
        james_bond.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                pushER();
            }
        });
        text.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int i, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
                pushER();
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
    private void pushER(){
        String texT = text.getText().toString();
        if(!texT.equals("")){
            InstantMessage hobbs = new InstantMessage(username, texT);
            ethan.child("Chats").push().setValue(hobbs);
            text.setText("");
        }
    }
    private void showDisplay(){
        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(RegisterActivity.CHAT_PREF, MODE_PRIVATE);
        username = prefs.getString(RegisterActivity.DISPLAY_NAME, null);
        if(username ==  null){
            username = "guest";
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, ethan, username);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        adapter.confusing();
    }

}
```

This is my InstantMessage class:

```
package com.example.codechat;

public class InstantMessage{
   private String user;
   private String message;
   public InstantMessage(String l, String k){
      user = l;
      message = k;
   }
   public InstantMessage(){

   }
   public String getMessage() {
      return message;
   }

   public String getUser() {
      return user;
   }
}
```

this is my database:

```
"Chats" : {
     "-MG3WxkPWaK-SFh7Q5M_" : "ynnh"
}
```

I could not find anything related to this error.
I used firebase Crashlytics and got the stack trace.
The syntax is quite different from the others.
The moment I type something in the editText it crashes.
Can you help me?
Edit:
I got a new error:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
       at com.example.codechat.CustomAdapter.getView(CustomAdapter.java:88)
       at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:3073)
       at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1305)
       at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1212)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20236)
       at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:716)
       at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:462)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20236)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6333)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
       at androidx.appcompat.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:146)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20236)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6333)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:747)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:629)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20236)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6333)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20236)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6333)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:747)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:629)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20236)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6333)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
       at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:3140)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20236)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2704)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1656)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1948)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1544)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7607)
       at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:911)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:686)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:622)
       at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:897)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7402)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include a sample of the JSON at `Chats` in your database (as text, no screenshots please). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: What you have within the `Chats` node is supposed to be an object of type `InstantMessage`? Please respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: Yes, it should be InstantMessage @AlexMamo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the following error:

> Fatal Exception: com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.example.codechat.InstantMessage

Because of the following line of code:

```
return snapshot.getValue(InstantMessage.class);
```

And this is because your `myDB` reference points to the `Chats` node that actually contains a String and **not** an `InstantMessage` object. To make it work, the database structure should look like this:

```
Firebase-root
  |
  --- Chats
       |
       --- -MG3WxkPWaK-SFh7Q5M_
               |
               --- user: "Alex"
               |
               --- message: "Hi, Jandroid!"
```

So as you can see you can't have dynamic properties, you should have the exact properties that you have in your `InstantMessage` class, so you can map a child right into an object of your `InstantMessage` class.

If you don't want to use a POJO class, then you can simply get the data from your actual structure like this:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference chatsRef = rootRef.child("Chats");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String user = ds.getKey();
            String message = ds.getValue(String.class);
            Log.d("TAG", user + " / " + message);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d("TAG", databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore potential errors!
    }
};
chatsRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

And the result in your logcat will be:

```
-MG3WxkPWaK-SFh7Q5M_ / ynnh
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220826/discussion-on-answer-by-alex-mamo-firebase-database-data-type-conversion-error).